# endianness influence in C++ code

Tags: c++, sockets, endianness

I know that this might be a silly question, but I am a newbie C++ developer and I need some clarifications about the endianness.

I have to implement a communication interface that relies on SCTP protocol in order to communicate between two different machines (one ARM based, and the other Intel based).

The aim is to:

1. encode messages into a stream of bytes to be sent on the socket (I used a vector of uint8_t, and positioned each byte of the different fields -taking care of splitting uint16/32/64 to single bytes- following big-endian convention)
2. send the bytestream via socket to the receiver (using stcp)
3. retrieve the stream and parse it in order to fill the message object with the correct elements (represented by header + TV information elements)

I am confused on where I could have problem with the endianness of the underlying architecture of the 2 machines in where the interface will be used. 
I think that taking care of splitting objects into single bytes and positioning them using big-endian can preclude that, at the arrival, the stream is represented differently, right? or am I missing something?

Also, I am in doubt about the role of C++ representation of multiple-byte variables, for example:

```
uint16_t var=0x0123;

//low byte 0x23 
uint8_t low = (uint8_t)var;

//hi byte 0x01
uint8_t hi = (uint8_t)(var >> 8);
```

This piece of code is endianness dependent or not? i.e. if I work on a big-endian machine I suppose that the above code is ok, but if it is little-endian, will I pick up the bytes in different order?

I've searched already for such questions but no one gave me a clear reply, so I have still doubts on this.

Thank you all in advance guys, have a nice day!

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&var)[0]` would be different depending of endianness.

Comment: You can `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>var` to avoid that verbose and confusing syntax.

Comment: Now that I think of it, `uint8_t` is not necessarily a typedef for `unsigned char` so reinterpreting part of a `uint16_t` as `uint8_t` is actually undefined.

Comment: @patatahooligan: Missing parenthesis if you message. `[0]` is mostly a place holder as `[1]` would also be used in the same problematic way.

Comment: And indeed for the pedantic UB part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This piece of code is endianness dependent or not?

No the code doesn't depend on endianess of the target machine. Bitwise operations work the same way as e.g. mathematical operators do.

They are independent of the internal representation of the numbers.

---

Though if you're exchanging data over the wire, you need to have a defined byte order known at both sides. Usually that's network byte ordering (i.e. big endian).

The functions of the [`htonx()` `ntohx()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html) family will help you do en-/decode the (multibyte) numbers correctly and transparently.

Comment: Ok, thank you. what about the stream part? the fact that I manually placed single bytes in big-endian format and then sent them over the socket, retrieved and decoded knowing that are in big endian order should go ok, right?

Comment: sorry I saw your edit just after posting the comment :) thank you, I'll definitely check those methods!

Comment: "On some implementations, these functions are defined as macros."    So sad that some library maintainers don't understand what they're meant to do when creating functions

Comment: @UkMonkey, is there a real reason to object to `#define htonl(x) (x)` on platforms where that's the natural implementation?  Now, if you were to implement them as macros *which expand their argument more than once*, then **that** would be incompetent.

Comment: @TobySpeight  2 jump to mind...   1. std::string blah;  htonl(blah)     2. namespace custom { char htonl(char*) {...}}   Just because it's an unlikely sequence of characters for devs to want to put together, doesn't mean it's ok.

Any reason why they can't just make an inline function to return x?

Comment: And you cannot have *"pointer on macro"*, so `&htonl` would be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The code you presented is endian-independent, and likely the *correct* approach for your use case.

What won't work, and is not portable, is code that depends on the memory layout of objects:

```
// Don't do this!
uint16_t var=0x0123;
auto p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&var);
uint8_t hi = p[0]; // 0x01 or 0x23 (probably!)
uint8_t lo = p[1]; // 0x23 or 0x01 (probably!)
```

(I've written *probably* in the comments to show that these are the likely real-world values, rather than anything specified by Standard C++)